# how to compare two columns in a single file in unix

Tags: bash, unix

My req is i need to get the output if the two columns are not equal below is my code.

The output is as below here my req is for example the first shouldnt be printed as both are equal the second should be printed as both are not equal.

```
cat testingfull.txt|sed -n '/"Exp_CDL_BOOKINGS_F"/,/TABLEATTRIBUTE NAME/p'|grep EXPRESSION | awk -F"\"" '{print $8,"=",$12}'

BOOK_DATE_KEY=BOOK_DATE_KEY
Lkp_BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY=iif( not  isnull(i_BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY) and isnull(iif(BOOK_DATE_KEY&lt;&gt;Lkp_BOOK_DATE_KEY, NULL)),null,i_BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY)
BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY=Lkp_BOOKINGS_FACT_KEY
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Compare columns in your awk command:

```
awk -F'"' '$8!=$12 {print $8,"=",$12}'
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `awk -F'"' '$8==$12 {print $8,"=",$12}{print $8,"!=",$12}'`?

Comment: @Ooker: Final output is as per OP's example from question.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you (trail this to your current line) :

```
... | awk -F'=' '$1!=$2'
```